# ImportError: cannot import name 'linux' from open3d

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a code on ubuntu 20.04 that uses open3d library, I've installed open3d using pip. However, when I run the code it shows

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'linux' from open3d
```

I tried installing tensorflow 1.11 but no use.

code:

```
from open3d import linux as open3d
from os.path import join
import numpy as np
import colorsys, random, os, sys
import pandas as pd
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_S3DIS.py", line 2, in <module>
    from RandLANet import Network
  File "/mnt/d/research/codes/randla-net/RandLANet.py", line 4, in <module>
    from helper_tool import DataProcessing as DP
  File "/mnt/d/research/codes/randla-net/helper_tool.py", line 1, in <module>
    from open3d import linux as open3d
ImportError: cannot import name 'linux' from open3d
```

Comment: which version of open3d did you install?

Comment: That should be in line 1, not line 2. Also, the rest of the code should be irrelevant. Can you clarify that?

Comment: Why do you think there should be a `linux` submodule?  I don't see that in the docs.

Comment: I installed version 0.10.0

Comment: @TimRoberts me neither ! but I tried running without it and it showed me error as it is calling this module in the rest of the code

Comment: Try to install the latest 0.13.0. Also see this http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/getting_started.html

Comment: Tried running what without the `linux`? As of `open3d` 0.13.0 there is no `linux` submodule so the code you're trying to run using the module might be necessary to debug the issue